# Problema con javascript al realizar pequeña calculadora

Tags: javascript

El enunciado dice así:

> Crea un bucle que te pida números por teclado hasta que se pulse 0. Al
> pulsar 0 se mostrará un mensaje indicando cuáles son los números que
> se han pulsado y la suma y el producto parcial de los mismos.

He hecho un while, pero no me muestra nada por pantalla cuando refresco la página, y el script no veo que puede fallar. Adjunto imagen de lo que deberia mostrarse:

[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlTfr.png)

Este es mi código:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var numeros;
    var sum;
    var str;
    while (numeros !=0) {
    numeros=prompt("Introduzca numeros, 0 para acabar");
      sum=sum+numeros;
      var producto=numeros;
      producto=producto*numeros;
      str=numeros+"     suma parcial= "+sum+"    producto parcial= "+producto+"\n";)
    }
      alert(str);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var numeros=1;
    var sum=0;
    var producto=1;
    var res="";
    while (numeros !=0) {
      numeros=prompt("Introduzca numeros, 0 para acabar")*1;
      if (numeros!=0){
        sum+=numeros;
        producto=producto*numeros;
        res+= numeros + "     suma parcial= " + sum + "    producto parcial= " + producto +" \n";
      }
    }
    alert(res);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Algunas variables no estaban inicializadas, y se estaban sustituyendo la respuesta. Solucionado.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo, y dale un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta: recordá que otros podrían tener el mismo problema que vos, y difícilmente encuentren tu pregunta si se titula "problema con...".

Answer (score 1):

el problema radica en que el script se está cargando pero no se está ejecutando, es decir, ningún elemento del body está interactuando (invocando) con el script.

Solución:

1. Usa el evento "onload" que se ejecuta cuando el "body " se carga por primera vez y desde allí llama a tu script.
2. Puedes poner todo el código del script en una función para manejarla más fácilmente.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="miFuncion()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function miFuncion() {
            // Escribe aquí tu código a ejecutar
            console.log('body cargado')
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aplicado a tu código, sería así:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="miFuncion()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function miFuncion() {
            var numeros;
            var sum = 0;
            var str;
            while (numeros !=0) {
                    numeros = prompt("Introduzca numeros, 0 para acabar");
                    sum = sum + parseInt(numeros);
                    var producto = numeros;
                    producto = producto * numeros;
                    str = numeros + "     suma parcial= " + sum + "    producto parcial= " + producto + "\n";
                    console.log(str)
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

saludos!

Comment: Buenas, no muestra nada cuando termina javascript y se muestra el body, aparece en blanco, como si no tuviera nada que mostrar, pero he descubierto que si comento la linea donde defino el resultado (str) si me ejecuta debe de haber algun fallo donde defino str...